# Session alternative in file upload using REST

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest

I'm building ASP.NET WEB API SPA-application using REST approach. I need to upload files so i can:

1. Tie uploaded files to current user
2. Validate uploaded count
3. Resize uploaded files and save their path to database

I't pretty easy when using Sessions. But it's bad practice to store state on the server when developing with REST approach.

Are there any alternatives to session in this case?

Comment: How do you currently use the session?

Comment: I don't use sessions now because Web API does not allow(there is a workaround but i don't want to use hacks)

Comment: Let me rephrase that: why do you think you need to use sessions? For what functionality exactly are you looking for an alternative?

Comment: I need to know exactly what files user uploaded, i need to know how many files were uploaded. After that these files should be resized and placed to database for that user.